# How do I add app services and other resources to an existing azure service fabric instance?

Tags: azure, service, azure-service-fabric

I created a service fabric asp.net core web API project in visual studio and published it to my Azure account. Everything works fine. Suppose my fabric name is myFabric and it has an app myApp. Now suppose I already have another completely different app myOldApp ( an existing Azure resource of type app-service ) in the same resource group. Is there any way I can just move that app service app myOldApp also to myFabric so that it's orchestration will also be managed by myFabric? One way I can I think of is to pull myOldApp down, move the code to the solution of myFabric project and start again, but is there a better way? Is there any option wherein from the portal I can directly select and then app service app myOldApp to myFabric seamless. Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct migration path from App Services to Service Fabric. You will need to pull the code from you app and deploy it into the service fabric cluster.

That being said, it should be fairly simple to get your code from app services and have it run in SF.

We don't have an explicit guide for Web Apps to SF. However there is one for Cloud Services to Service Fabric which you might find useful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service